# Namespace error in xaml for DataTemplateSelector

Tags: xaml, xml-namespaces, datatemplateselector

I've an xaml code in which I've used DataTemplateSelector.But it shows me namespace error.Code behind for it is written inside "TimeSheet.Views.DataTemplate" namespace and xaml code is written in "TimeSheet.Views" namespace.How should I write namespace for it?

outline of my xaml code is:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow 
    x:Name="MainWin"
    x:Class="TimeSheet.DayView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TimeSheet.Views.DataTemplateSpace"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    Title="DayView" Width="590" Height="590">

<l:DayViewListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
          DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
          EditableDataTemplate="{StaticResource EditableDataTemplate}"/>
```

Code Behind for it is,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
//using System.Windows.DependencyProperty;
//using System.ComponentModel.DependencyPropertyDescriptor;
using HarvestApp;

namespace TimeSheet.Views.DataTemplateSpace
{
public class DayViewListDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate EditableDataTemplate { get; set; }
    //public DataTemplate EnumDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,DependencyObject container)
    {
      //some code
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I got the problem.There is not namespace error actually.You just have to write key for your DataTemplates, if it's outside mergeddictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
    <Controls:MetroWindow 
        x:Name="MainWin"
        x:Class="TimeSheet.DayView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TimeSheet.Views.DataTemplateSpace"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="DayView" Width="590" Height="590">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate"> //here you must write key 
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <TextBox Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0"    Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding StartTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding StopTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding ProjectNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="130"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="71"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Editable DataTemplate -->
       <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableDataTemplate">   //here you must write key 
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StartTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StopTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="130"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding projectList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name" SelectedValue="{Binding selectedProjectid}" />                    
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

<l:DayViewListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
              DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
              EditableDataTemplate="{StaticResource EditableDataTemplate}"/>

        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Window.Resources>
```